# Magento 2: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressExtension as array

Tags: magento2

I'm having troubles with trying to get city_id extension attribute from a RateRequest object to use it with in_array PHP function, but I'm getting: `Cannot use object of type Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressExtension as array`

The thing is that I've a logger set and doing `json_encode($request->getData())` returns the following JSON:

```
{"all_items":[{}],"dest_country_id":"CL","dest_region_id":913,"dest_region_code":"R02","dest_street":"","dest_city":"OLLAGUE","dest_postcode":"-","package_value":42990,"package_value_with_discount":42990,"package_weight":0.907,"package_qty":1,"extension_attributes":{"city_id":"903"},"package_physical_value":42990,"free_method_weight":0.907,"store_id":"1","website_id":"1","free_shipping":false,"base_currency":{},"package_currency":{},"limit_carrier":null,"base_subtotal_incl_tax":42990,"country_id":"CL","region_id":"809","city":null,"postcode":"83200"}
```

As you can see, there's `city_id` value on `extension_attributes` key, assuming `json_encode` return a string, I tried to get with `$request['extension_attributes']['city_id']` but it's returning the error. How is that possible? I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have converted it to json_encode, if you want to get it as `$request['extension_attributes']['city_id']` then you need to use json_decode to decode the returned json function first

Answer (score 0):

In your first json_encode it change first level json to array but city is again it slef an object `"extension_attributes":{"city_id":"903"}` either again use json_encode or use like following

`$request['extension_attributes']->city_id` to get city value